# JSch and Expect4j libraries in java (Trying to send commands via ssh)

Tags: java, ssh, command, jsch, reboot

everybody:

I'm trying to write a programme in java which allows me to reboot my router via ssh. However, I'm having a problem when trying to send the router command "restart" with Expect4j. This is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelShell;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import expect4j.Expect4j;


public class Router {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession("user", "host");
        session.setPassword("password");
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect(60 * 1000);
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");


        Expect4j expect = new Expect4j(channel.getInputStream(),
                channel.getOutputStream());
        channel.setInputStream(System.in);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

        expect.send("restart");


        channel.connect();



    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}

}
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:         org/apache/oro/text/regex/Perl5Matcher
    at expect4j.Expect4j.<init>(Expect4j.java:37)
    at expect4j.Expect4j.<init>(Expect4j.java:61)
    at Router.main(Router.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

I don't really know why the output gives me a "Class not found" exception.

Have you got any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need Expect4j?

Comment: I finally worked it out without Expect4j. At first I thought I would need that library, but then I realized I did not. Thank you very much anyway. :-)